# Sum of different attributes for a user

Tags: sql

Suppose my database is

```
id visit
```

Users can visit A or B.  So some data might be

```
1 A
1 B
1 B
2 A
3 B
2 B
3 B
```

I want to get

```
id A B
1  1 2
2  1 1
3  0 2
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Any reason for the downvotes?

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but the question is not so clear and doesn't show any research effort from your, so I'm assuming downvotes are for similar reasons. Can you please edit your question to make it more clear?

Comment: You probably use some mixture of [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) and [COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html).  This is assuming you're using MySQL.

Comment: It's a fairly easy question, I didn't think listing the things that didn't work was really necessary.  Surely someone with more SQL expertise than me will just know how to do it and doesn't need clues?

Comment: It looks perfectly clear to me :) You may want to add what database you're using as they often have slightly different SQL syntax to each other.

Comment: You may be assuming the question is easy. but then again, it is others who are reading it and down voting they will have different perspective than you. You should also give as much information as possible. You will not have a database  with column id & visit, we have to assume that it is a table. You may also have to add which SQL server you are trying to use as that will potentially impact syntax. The Questions in StackOverFlow should show research effort of what you have done, otherwise you will be down voted. Best of Luck. You anyways got answers. Best of luck.

Comment: While I agree with most of your points, precision of language usually comes along about the same time as a firm understanding of the topic at hand. Andrew at least made the effort to reduce the question to the an example that allowed the problem to be understood quickly. This is a very simple SQL question and if he's known enough to post this question in precise clear language, he'd probably have known enough to answer it himself.

Comment: I had a blind-spot moment; as you can tell from the title I wasn't sure how to describe what it was I wanted to do.  And I just plain forget about the count() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it on SQL Server.

[image]

It's really weird, but stackoverflow wouldn't let me post that query, so I had to post a screen grab.

Comment: What about the code would it not let you post?  Did it give you some weird error?  Did you wrap it in backticks?  Probably not helpful, considering you've got a ton of rep.

Comment: I had the exact same reply as above ending at the query. It just gave me a generic non-helpful error message with no clue as to why. I've had it before and it's always to do with posting SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is as a simple aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when visit = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as A,
       sum(case when visit = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as B
from t
group by id
```

Comment: +1 I prefer your answer to mine :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like:

```
SELECT v.user_id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visit vv WHERE vv.user_id = v.user_id AND vv.loc = 'A') as visitA, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visit vv WHERE vv.user_id = v.user_id AND vv.loc = 'B') as visitB
FROM visit v
GROUP BY v.user_id
```

Assuming the table is called visit and the fields "user_id" and "loc".